# How to add first names and last names to an array as keys => values and display them?

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>practice</title>

  </head>

  <body>
<!-- $f_name = firstname-->
<!-- $l_name = lastname-->

    <?php
    echo "------------------------<br>";
    echo "<b>Participant Input</b><br>";
    echo "------------------------<br><br>";
    ?>

    <form action="practice.php" method="get">
      <!-- enabeled for bookmarking (insecure)-->

      <label>First Name: </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="f_name"/><br>

      <!-- we gonna refer the name  -->
      <label>Last Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="l_name"/><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>

    </form>

    <?php

    if(!empty($_GET) && array_key_exists('f_name', $_GET) &&
    array_key_exists('l_name', $_GET)){

      //get method and key existance
      $f_name = $_GET['f_name'];
      $l_name = $_GET['l_name'];

      //from the form above
      if(isset($l_name) && !empty($l_name)){

        //verify name existance
        echo "First Name: " . " $f_name <br>" .
        "Last Name: " . " $l_name <br>" ;

        $full_names = array();
        $name_array= array($f_name => $l_name);
        $best_names= array_push($full_names, $name_array);
        print_r($full_names);

      }
    }

    ?>

    </body>

  </html>
```

**The output I'm getting:**
First Name: Marie
Last Name: Minas
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Marie] => Minas ) )

**The output I'm expecting to get:**
First Name: Marie
Last Name: Minas
First Name: Dan
Last Name: White
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Marie] => Minas )
        [1] => Array ( [Dan]   => White ))

**The Method I prefer to use**

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
echo "{$key} => {$value} ";
print_r($arr);
}
```

**My version of the Method(not working)**

```
$full_names = array();
    foreach ($full_names as $key => $value) {
      $key = $f_name;
      $value = $l_name;
      $key = $key++;
      $value = $value++;
     print_r($full_names);    
  }
```

Comment: What are you sending in `f_name` and `l_name`? It sounds like you may want to allow arrays with `f_name[]` and `l_name[]` and then `explode()` them (or similar).

Comment: Trying to display them as First_name => Last_name

Comment: that sounds possible to! Do you think there is anyway to use foreach statement?

Comment: As Obsidian Age said, you should change HTML. You should add brackets to input field names to allow you to send all first names and last names as an array. It will collect all first name un last name input fields in two arrays. Then you can write a function to create an associative array if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks my dear .I'm still researching about that and trying different methods. Haven't gotten any results yet.

Answer (score 0):

When you re-submit your form, the existing value gets overwrite with the new one. There are many ways to achieve the expected output.

1. Save the user input values in the database and fetch the data from the database.
2. Store the value in `SESSION` as shown below.

   ```
   <?php session_start();?>
   ```

   ```
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>practice</title>
   ```

   ```
   <?php
   echo "------------------------<br>";
   echo "<b>Participant Input</b><br>";
   echo "------------------------<br><br>";
   ?>

   <form action="practice.php" method="get">
     <!-- enabeled for bookmarking (insecure)-->

     <label>First Name: </label><br>
     <input type="text" name="f_name"/><br>

     <!-- we gonna refer the name  -->
     <label>Last Name</label><br>
     <input type="text" name="l_name"/><br>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>

   </form>

   <?php

   if(!empty($_GET) && array_key_exists('f_name', $_GET) &&
   array_key_exists('l_name', $_GET)){

     //get method and key existance
     $f_name = $_GET['f_name'];
     $l_name = $_GET['l_name'];

     //from the form above
     if(isset($l_name) && !empty($l_name)){

       //verify name existance
       $_SESSION['name_array']= array($f_name => $l_name);
       $_SESSION['full_names'][] = $_SESSION['name_array'];
       foreach($_SESSION['full_names'] as $data){
           foreach($data as $key=>$val){
           echo "First Name: " . " $key <br>" .
               "Last Name: " . " $val <br>" ;
           }
       }
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($_SESSION['full_names']);
     }
   }

   ?>

   </body>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and neat coding. But it still doesn't echo all the names each time I add a new name. Do you know if there is any other method I can use ? Or is it  out of PHP scope? Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

Brother just try this simple way

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
?>
<form action="" method="get">
    <label>First Name: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="f_name"/><br>
    <label>Last Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="l_name"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
</form>
<?php
if(!empty($_GET) && array_key_exists('f_name', $_GET) &&
array_key_exists('l_name', $_GET)){
    //get method and key existance
    $f_name = $_GET['f_name'];
    $l_name = $_GET['l_name'];
    //from the form above
    if(isset($l_name) && !empty($l_name)){
        $full_names = array();
        $name_array= array(
            'f_name' => $f_name,
            'l_name' => $l_name
        );
        $best_names= array_push($full_names, $name_array);
    }
}
```

[image]

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks you my dear. It's a very beautiful and useful code but still it doesn't print all the names together at once each time there is a new name added.     Do you know if there is any other method I can use ? Or is it out of PHP scope?     Thanks a lot though!